# Laravel: how to insert an array with radio button per row

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I want to insert a different status for each student per row where my status are (**present, absent,late,others**)

**Here's my view**

```
<div align="center"><b>List of Students Enrolled</b></div>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
   <th>Student ID</th>
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <th>Present</th>
    <th>Late</th>
    <th>Absent</th>
    <th>Others</th>
    <th>Comments</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach ($users as $users)
            <tr>
      <td>{{ $users->student_id  }} </td>
       <td>{{ $users->student_firstname  }} {{ $users->student_lastname  }}</td> 
    <td>{{ Form::radio('student['.$users->student_id.'][status]', 'present' , true) }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::radio('student['.$users->student_id.'][status]', 'late' ) }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::radio('student['.$users->student_id.'][status]', 'absent') }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::radio('student['.$users->student_id.'][status]', 'others') }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::text('student['.$users->student_id.'][comment]') }}</td>

          @endforeach
```

Is there anyway i can insert this inside a function in my controller?

Thank You!

Comment: please be clear in what you are trying to do

Comment: I want to insert in my table the different status of each student per row 
Let's say student1 is present, student2 is absent .... using the radio button  as an array for each student

Comment: Why would you want the names to be arrays? you can just create different name values using string concatenation as: `'student'.$users->student_id`

Comment: uhm.... no actually,  what i want to achieve is getting the result(e.g. present, absent, late, others) of each student which i refer to each row are student id

Answer (score 0):

`Input::get('student')[1]['status'];`  in your controller should return the status of the first student and similarly for the other students.

```
foreach( Input::get('student') as $key => $student ) {
  if( array_key_exists( 'status', $student )) {
     $s = Student::find( $key );
     $s->status = $student['status'];
     $s->save()
  }
}
```

should save the status of every student to the table.

Comment: `Student::find( $key )->status = $student['status'];` assigns only a value to the `student` object. You'll need to call `save()` on the object.

Comment: Hi  i tried it like this:

 foreach (Input::get('student')as $key  => $value ) {

                if( array_key_exists('status', $value))
                {
                    $s = User::find( $key )->status = $value['status'];   
                    $attendance = new Attendances();
                    $attendance->status = $s;
                    $attendance->save();
}
}

Its still giving me the wrong record :c  am i missing something? or did i type something wrong? :(

Comment: I'm having an undefined offset when i declare

Input::get('student')[1]['status'];

Comment: Where are you saving the status, in the User model or the Attendance model? If you are saving it into the Attendance model, leave the `User::find(...)` and simply `$attendance = new Attendance; $attendance->status = $value['status']; $attendance->user_id = $key`